# Not able to Start rabbitmq server in centos 7 using systemctl

Tags: rabbitmq, centos7

I am trying to start the rabbitmq server in centos 7. I installed erlang as it is a dependency to rabbitmq-server. Package erlang.x86_64 0:R16B-03.7.el7 .I then Installed rabbitmq using package rabbitmq-server-3.2.2-1.noarch.rpm. Installation was successful. I enabled management console uisng rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management. But while starting the service rabbitmq-server it fails.

```
[root@tve-centos ~]# systemctl start rabbitmq-server.service
Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed. See 'systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
[root@tve-centos ~]# systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service
rabbitmq-server.service - LSB: Enable AMQP service provided by RabbitMQ broker
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/rabbitmq-server)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2014-09-12 13:07:05 PDT; 8s ago
  Process: 20235 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/rabbitmq-server start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 12 13:07:04 tve-centos su[20245]: (to rabbitmq) root on none
Sep 12 13:07:05 tve-centos su[20296]: (to rabbitmq) root on none
Sep 12 13:07:05 tve-centos su[20299]: (to rabbitmq) root on none
Sep 12 13:07:05 tve-centos rabbitmq-server[20235]: Starting rabbitmq-server: FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_{log, _err}
Sep 12 13:07:05 tve-centos rabbitmq-server[20235]: rabbitmq-server.
Sep 12 13:07:05 tve-centos systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 12 13:07:05 tve-centos systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Enable AMQP service provided by RabbitMQ broker.
Sep 12 13:07:05 tve-centos systemd[1]: Unit rabbitmq-server.service entered failed state.
```

and logs shows  /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_log
    BOOT FAILED
    ===========

```
Error description:
   {could_not_start,rabbitmq_management,
                    {could_not_start_listener,[{port,15672}],eacces}}

Log files (may contain more information):
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@tve-centos.log
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@tve-centos-sasl.log
```

but no process is using port 15672

**But if I try to start it using /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server** .I successfully started the service. But my requirements are to start it using the systemctl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a port issue. To confirm that

```
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl disable firewalld
```

And disable SELinux for the time being in /etc/selinux/config file

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

Try reboot your machine and see whether the issue persists.

Comment: As a rule, one should always run a firewall and leave SELINUX enabled; so, once the problem is identified, turning these back on is highly advised. You can run tcpdump to help figure out what firewall ports are blocked (or start by enabling the ones rabbitmq is known to need), and you can use audit2allow to figure out what SELINUX policy/boolean is blocking the service. See @chriscowley's answer.

Answer (score 21):

Better answer would be to actually fix SELinux and the firewall.

Open the port:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5672/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
setsebool -P nis_enabled 1
```

That works for me.

Comment: I'm on `CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)` and I get an error on the last command `Boolean nisenabled is not defined`

Comment: @pyCthon try without my typo :-) the boolean is actually `nis_enabled` not `nisenabled`. Sorry

Comment: Thank you! I finally got it running with this method too. I was missing the setsebool command bit

Comment: You should probably correct the same typo on your blog. ;)

Comment: And this doesn't expose the port to the world right? Or where can you configure Rabbit to listen only on the loopback interface?

Answer (score 1):

After running this command:

```
[root@gcp-hehe-amqp ~]# /sbin/service rabbitmq-server start
```

And getting the error:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start rabbitmq-server.service
Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details"
```

After many attempts, I solved the error by following this:

1. run command: 
   `firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5672/tcp`
2. then: `firewall-cmd --reload`
3. change this: `SELINUX=disabled` at /etc/selinux/config
4. Enable the proxy protocol to true at /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf

   **proxy_protocol = true**